# as_json call override method with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

How can I call a method with params inside `as_json`?

**Details:**

I'm using [as_json](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json), It allows me to call methods, but all methods should be without params, how can I use it to call a method with params?

**Example:**

Person object has method `name` as the following:

```
def name long=false
  return long == true ? self.long_name : self.attributes["name"]
end
```

I have person_object, how can call `person_object.as_json(only: [:id, :name])`

How can I send params `long=true` when I call method `name`?

Comment: `as_json` doesn't allow to call methods. It allows to include **the result of some method calls**.

Answer (score 1):

In short, I don't think you can.

You'd need to either add a method with no arguments on person that calls name how you want:

```
def long_name
  name(true)
end
```

And then do `person_object.as_json(only: [:id, :long_name], methods: :long_name)`

Or modify the return from `as_json` yourself:

```
person_object.as_json(only: :id).merge(name: person_object.name(true))
```

The second option has the name attribute as you want it (rather than renaming it to long name) but is a bit more cumbersome.